# How to display Image from outside project directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, imageurl

I have an Image Path which is of D: drive and I want to display that Image on my Image Control of asp.net.So, how to provide file path to Image.ImageUrl?

> "D:/Folder/001_001.jpg"

I tried with server.MapPath() method but doesn't work.

Comment: I think you are mixing things up. Image URL is the url that is being queried/accessed from the browser, it has very little to do with local path. Also project directory is not a notion that is useful in the context of a running website. Surely it is deployed somewhere else and is not run from a developer machine where the project directory is located.

Answer (score 1):

If you're deploying in IIS, you could create a virtual directory `Images` that would point towards `D:/Folder`, then you could set your ImageUrl to `~/Images/001_001.jpg.jpg`.

An alternative solution could be to create a symlink between the two folders. You would run something like the following in cmd `mklink /D ""D:/Folder" "[YouProjectPath]/Images"`, then set your ImageUrl to `~/Images/001_001.jpg.jpg`. I would stay away from this though as it would only work on a machine where the project lives in the exact same path as yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can make local path as following "`file:///D:/Folder/001_001.jpg`".

However, it's **strongly not recommended** to use this practice even if your site is planned to stay on your local computer only and will never been deployed to real Internet. You should copy / upload the file to your site's subdirectory 'Images' and then use the relative path '`~/Images/001_001.jpg`'.